# Read Excel data using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to read excel sheet data using VBA i want to read excel data from local path and get all mailID's in comma separated. Please help me to achieve this. In excel Sheet i have Sheet name as Sheet 1 in which i have 2 columns S.No & MailID in which i want MailID Column data in comma separated.

Code:

```
Public Sub AutomateOutlook()
        
    Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem
        
    Set mail = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
        
    Dim OAtmt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim strProgramName As String        
    Dim strFileName As String
        
    For Each OAtmt In mail.Attachments
        OAtmt.SaveAsFile "C:\Development\Files\" & OAtmt.FileName
    Next OAtmt
        
    Call ReadDataFromCloseFile
        
End Sub
        
Public Sub ReadDataFromCloseFile()
        
    Dim src As Workbook
    Dim MailID As String

    Set src = Workbooks.Open("C:\Development_Avecto\Files\MailID.xlsx", True, True)
        
    For i = 1 To 1
        Cells(i, 1) = _
            src.Worksheets("MailID.xlsx").Cells(i + 1, 1)
    Next i
    src.Close
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you really need accomplishing... So, in the first sheet of the respective workbook **are there only two columns** (the mentioned one)? Or many columns and that two between them? Do you need a third column keeping the two columns values, comma separated? Do you want saving a CSV, comma delimited for the sheet in discussion? Or what? Please, edit your question and try better describing what you really need accomplishing. It may be clear for you, but in order to be helped, we must also understand what is to be done. Your code does not help at all, to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example using a Function to return the data from ColB as a comma-separated string:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim allMails As String
    
    allMails = ReadDataFromCloseFile()
    
    'do something with allMails

End Sub

Public Function ReadDataFromCloseFile()
        
    Dim src As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, mails As String, sep As String

    Set src = Workbooks.Open("C:\Development_Avecto\Files\MailID.xlsx", True, True)
    Set ws = src.Worksheets("Sheet 1") 'sheet with your data
    
    For i = 1 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'last-occupied row in Col B
        mails = mails & sep & ws.Cells(i, "B").Value
        sep = ","
    Next i
    src.Close savechanges:=False
    ReadDataFromCloseFile = mails
End Function
```